# Программа ломается при разборе ini-файла

Tags: python, файлы

Пробую разобрать ini-файл (переменная `file`), но при обращении по индексу возникает исключение:

```
contFile = file.readlines()
print(contFile)   # ['[MAIN]\r', '\r\n', 'comments=Test1\r\n']

cont = contFile[1].split('=')[1]   # IndexError: list index out of range
```

Вопрос: Как избавиться от `'\r\n'` в списке? Есть ощущение, что именно они мешают выполниться программе.

Comment: может проверить каждый элемент списка на .isspace() ? Мне не до конца понятно где там список, если в файл пишется. contFile?

Comment: contFile и есть список изначально состоящий из 2-х элементов ['[MAIN]', 'comments=Test1'], после всех не хитрых операций он получается уже из 3-х собственно как указан выше и cont = contFile[1].split('=')[1].replace(self.forIf, textCont) уже не применить сюда если не избавиться от '\r\n'

Comment: мог бы посоветовать .strip(), но думаю Вы до этого и сами бы догадались.

Comment: Мне кажется проблема таится где то в fil.write(''.join(contFile))

Comment: .strip() пробовал не помогает( к тому же этот метод применим к строковой переменной, а в данном случае у меня элемент списка

Comment: а разве он не является строкой?

Comment: q = ['[MAIN]\r', '\r\n', 'comments=Test1\r\n']
q[2].strip()
'comments=Test1'

Comment: Элемент, да строковый, но мне необходимо получить целый список без '\r\n' элемнта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
contFile = [line for line in contFile if line.strip()]
```

А для вырезания \n и \r из элементов уже .strip()

Например:

```
cont = contFile[1].strip().split('=')[1].replace(self.forIf, textCont)
```

UPD

```
In [189]: contFile = ['[MAIN]\r', '\r\n', 'comments=Test1\r\n']

In [190]: contFile = [line.strip() for line in contFile if line.strip()]

In [191]: contFile
Out[191]: ['[MAIN]', 'comments=Test1']
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш вариант, но не помогло(

Comment: тогда я не понимаю, что именно нужно. Посмотрите, я обновил ответ.

Comment: Да Ваш метод работает поставлю +, может кому пригодится, но к сожалению мне не помогло, наверное надо копать глубже в саму функцию

Comment: так выводите промежуточные значения, или используйте ipdb (pdb), смотрите что не так, если что - пишите.

Comment: Вот пробую по Вашему:
0-я итерация ['[MAIN]\r', '\r\n', 'comments=Test1\r\n']
1-я итерация ['[MAIN]', 'comments=Test1']
2-я итерация ['[MAIN]comments=Test1']
Получается для одноразового использования этот метод подходит, если дальше - нет

Comment: Так Вы когда записываете в новый файл, вставляйте \n для перехода на новую строку.